# Interference between Branch WebSDK and link tracking?

Tags: branch.io

We are currently using Branch IO for our attribution of app installations. However, we have seen some troubling elements regarding tracking - specifically, that link context is lost in some flows. This seems to have started when we integrated the Web SDK.

The flow is as follows:

1. From within our iOS application (that has Branch integrated), I initiate an SMS to be sent to myself (a branch link with some referral parameters including campaign)
2. After the SMS is sent, I delete the application from my phone.
3. I reset my Advertiser ID on my phone and clear my browser cookies
4. I click the link in my SMS messages (and this initiates tracking event in Branch Dashboard). The link eventually drops me onto a page that I control, which ALSO has the Branch WebSDK installed. This fires page events.
5. I then click the button on the page that takes me to the app store, install the application, and then fire it up.
6. I see in the dashboard that an install event has occurred, but it does NOT associate it with the initial campaign from the SMS.

Is this expected? My current theory is that the WebSDK fires a new event, which now is tracked by Branch as the latest event and since the WebSDK doesn't have any of the tracking parameters from the SMS campaign, it gets lost.

I have tried to debug this but once it goes into Branch, I'm not sure how to tell where things are lost. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the install associated to the particular link? I.e. do you receive the link data in your app.
Is the event if your dashboard an `install` event or `open` event?
Do you get `is_first_session` as true? Branch has a logic in place which detects a reinstall even when you reset the IDFA.

Comment: Hi @AmrutaDeshmukh! Thanks for the response! The event in my dashboard is an install event (not a reinstall) and it appears that it is the first session ("Device First Seen Timestamp" and "Session Start" are both set at the same timestamp as the event itself. Is there a separate area where I can retrieve the "is_first_session" value?

Comment: You can get the `is_first_session` value in your app. If you have the branch SDK in your mobile app, you can get the value in the branch.initsession method. If you still continue to face issues, could you please write to `integrations@branch.io`.